# Indentar código HTML no Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

Como faz pra indentar o código HTML no Notepad++? Já salvei o arquivo como `.html` e a indentação não está sendo automática. A cada <kbd>enter</kbd>, em vez de adicionar um espaço (tab), está indo para linha abaixo como se fosse um texto normal. Há algum atalho que eu possa indentar todo o código já existente e fazer com que a indentação passe a ser feita?

Comment: Use o sublime text, há uma extensão especifica para identar o seu código.

Comment: quero continuar com o Notepad++. Obrigada pela sugestão.

Answer (score 7):

Você [pode usar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad) o `XML Tools`.

- Instale o XML Tools pelo Plugin Manager.
- Use o atalho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (*ou* 
  menu -> Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty Print)

Answer (score 2):

Olá para indentar no Notepad++ eu utilizo as teclas shift+tab selecionando um trecho ou o código completo com as teclas ctrl+A.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -2):

Instale o plugin Ident By Fold. Depois é só ir em plugin, Ident by fold, ident file.

Answer (score -2):

Tem vários sites que prestam esse serviço grátis,
eu uso esse:

https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Copia seu código e cola lá, pede pra formatar, dai cópia de volta para seu editor... e já era, é bem intuitivo, fácil de usar e não precisa instalar nada.